# 6 tomcat installation on same server [micro services project]

Tags: tomcat, multiple-instances

As part of a micro services project we are planning to install six tomcats on a single server. This is the first time installing these many tomcats or implementing micro services, so looking for guidance on best practices.

I'm debating on either to install all tomcats as diff installations or go with one catalina_home and different catalina_bases. Though i have read about using different catalina_base concept in many blogs, many people i have spoken to have never used this in an enterprise company. please do correct me if I am wrong and let me know if this is a widely used option? and what specific advantages it would provide.

Also i will really appreciate if any one can provide guidance on some best practices installing these many tomcats, that would make the operations easier in the future.

Comment: There is no advantage in having 6 copies of Tomcat's libraries and it will generate additional work during upgrades. I would debate whether multiple instances of Tomcat are necessary, but certainly use several `CATALINA_BASE` if you have to.

Comment: Installing more than one Tomcat is bad practice.  I ran up to 40 applications in one, and a number of them weren't micro.

Comment: It's recomended to use docker containers for microservices architecture. Install one tomcat to one container and run multiple containers on the same server. If you want to run different microservices in different servers you need to use container orchestrators: kubernetes and docker swarm are the most popular.

Comment: @Gerard - As it is a micro services application, we are restricted to running only one application in one tomcat

Comment: @RajK - every app in Tomcat has its own classloader and is mostly independent from the others. With one JVM running, you will not have to worry to split resources (most notably memory) between applications.